# ¿Cómo renombrar un componente automáticamente con Angular?

Tags: angular

Si para **generar un componente automáticamente**, con *Angular CLI*, usamos el comando:

```
ng generate nombre-nuevo-componente
```

lo que genera los ficheros del componente y los registra, ¿**hay una forma de renombrarlo automáticamente**, registrando a su vez el nuevo componente, eliminando los datos del nombre antiguo?

Answer (score 1):

No, no existe un modo de hacerlo automáticamente con Angular CLI, pero existe una utilidad creada exclusivamente para renombrar componentes, llamada [ng-rn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-rn). Los pasos para usarla son:

1. Instalarla: `npm i -g ng-rn`
2. Acceder al directorio donde está declarado el componente (igual que cuando vas a crearlo).
3. Escribir `ng-rn <nombre-actual> <nuevo-nombre>`

Comment: El comando seria: `ng-rn nombre-antiguo nombre-nuevo` o `ng-rn nombre-nuevo` una vez situados en el directorio del componente? no me acaban de funcionar ninguna de estas opciones, me salen varios mensajes de error.

Comment: Perdona, al no marcar como código el comando, lo que aparece entre `<>` se vuelve invisible... en teoría es como dices

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Error 1, si estoy en el directorio que contiene el del componente es: `(node:5056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`, error 2: `node:5056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.`. Error 3: `(node:5056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.`. Si entro al directorio del componente antes de tratar de renombrarlo cambia `node:5056` por `node:3012`

Answer (score 0):

Ej: Si tienes un componente llamado "puentes" dentro de "component" para renombrarlo "tunel", o sea, que component/puentes quede cómo componente/tunel. Tendrías que llegar a la carpeta component a traves del cdm (en caso de windows) y ahí dentro poner: ng-rn puentes tunel , y creo que tiene que funcionarte. Suerte.